# Netlify npm run build fails for Nuxt deploy

Tags: deployment, build, nuxt.js, netlify, netlify-cli

I followed this documentation https://nuxtjs.org/faq/netlify-deployment/ for SPA applications. This is my configuration: 
[Deploy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbzN6.png)

When I do `npm run build` to my Nuxt project locally everything works and the `.nuxt` folder that contains `dist`is generated too, nevertheless, in Netlify it won't work. 
Here is the deploy log which main issue is **failed during stage 'building site': Deploy directory 'dist' does not exist**. Here I'll paste the complete log:

```
3:52:58 PM: build-image version: 9cade8af58c2cf3a17a1e9433d2e979149488837
3:52:58 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.5
3:52:58 PM: buildbot version: 2d05064ce3dd2eb95d282a24602ab707dd9581e8
3:52:58 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
3:52:58 PM: Starting to download cache of 212.5MB
3:52:59 PM: Finished downloading cache in 1.384846269s
3:52:59 PM: Starting to extract cache
3:53:09 PM: Finished extracting cache in 10.185000282s
3:53:10 PM: Finished fetching cache in 11.702997628s
3:53:10 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
3:53:10 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
3:53:11 PM: Starting build script
3:53:11 PM: Installing dependencies
3:53:13 PM: Started restoring cached node version
3:53:16 PM: Finished restoring cached node version
3:53:17 PM: v10.18.0 is already installed.
3:53:19 PM: Now using node v10.18.0 (npm v6.13.4)
3:53:19 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
3:53:21 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
3:53:21 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
3:53:21 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
3:53:21 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
3:53:22 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
3:53:22 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
3:53:22 PM: unset GOOS;
3:53:22 PM: unset GOARCH;
3:53:22 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
3:53:22 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
3:53:22 PM: go version >&2;
3:53:22 PM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
3:53:22 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
3:53:22 PM: Installing missing commands
3:53:22 PM: Verify run directory
3:53:22 PM: Executing user command: npm run build
3:53:22 PM: > marketplace@1.0.0 build /opt/build/repo
3:53:22 PM: > nuxt build
3:53:24 PM: ℹ Production build
3:53:24 PM: ✔ Builder initialized
3:53:24 PM: ✔ Nuxt files generated
3:53:25 PM: ℹ Compiling Client
3:53:42 PM: ✔ Client: Compiled successfully in 17.17s
3:53:42 PM: ℹ Compiling Server
3:53:48 PM: ✔ Server: Compiled successfully in 5.39s
3:53:48 PM: Hash: 68bf0ef29d3fb5c8e150
3:53:48 PM: Version: webpack 4.41.5
3:53:48 PM: Time: 17174ms
3:53:48 PM: Built at: 01/05/2020 8:53:42 PM
3:53:48 PM:                          Asset       Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
3:53:48 PM: ../server/client.manifest.json   28.2 KiB          [emitted]
3:53:48 PM:        052eb8747a05f1304a0a.js   4.38 KiB       5  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/Marketplace/_id
3:53:48 PM:        05acc90986191e1ad517.js  264 bytes       9  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/Sso/index
3:53:48 PM:        2ab3d6553077491b19d2.js   4.74 KiB       8  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/Sso/_token
3:53:48 PM:        3664b44a9c9732b7d2e0.js   32.4 KiB      13  [emitted] [immutable]  vendors.app
3:53:48 PM:        4b9707aba77b0333f36b.js    163 KiB       2  [emitted] [immutable]  commons.app
3:53:48 PM:        5488203ab0561699ec41.js     17 KiB      11  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/index
3:53:48 PM:        619f0bd9f2a9459ad28a.js  264 bytes       7  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/Pricing/index
3:53:48 PM:        65dc97af8f4b0160ebf2.js  265 bytes      10  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/Tools/index
3:53:48 PM:        80fa73e83c4cec08f53b.js   60.1 KiB       1  [emitted] [immutable]  app
3:53:48 PM:                       LICENSES  876 bytes          [emitted]
3:53:48 PM:        af478362505be97ffe5e.js   8.57 KiB       6  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/Marketplace/index
3:53:48 PM:        bc2f7cdf3afe2ac74b48.js  264 bytes       3  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/Contact/index
3:53:48 PM:        c14d23663ea237774ac6.js   10.7 KiB       4  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/Marketplace/Requested/_id
3:53:48 PM:        ca77d1bfd2f5f229c948.js   54.5 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  vendors.pages/Marketplace/Requested/_id.pages/Marketplace/index.pages/index
3:53:48 PM:        e8d8275edcf2097334df.js   2.53 KiB      12  [emitted] [immutable]  runtime
3:53:48 PM:             fonts/066dc24.woff   34.1 KiB          [emitted]
3:53:48 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Deploy directory 'dist' does not exist
3:53:48 PM:            fonts/0a4b5c5.woff2   27.8 KiB          [emitted]
3:53:48 PM:             fonts/1af04b3.woff   35.8 KiB          [emitted]
3:53:48 PM:            fonts/3650a3f.woff2   25.9 KiB          [emitted]
3:53:48 PM:             fonts/4f07e73.woff   33.8 KiB          [emitted]
3:53:48 PM:             fonts/5b8b69a.woff   33.9 KiB          [emitted]
3:53:48 PM: Shutting down logging, 46 messages pending
3:53:48 PM:            fonts/6cbb85d.woff2   25.9 KiB          [emitted]
3:53:48 PM:             fonts/807f943.woff   32.8 KiB          [emitted]
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was having this same issue, then i figured that i forgot to run `yarn generate` before `yarn build`.
Also in your .gitignore remove `dist` there and it should work just fine.

Comment: Actually, `yarn generate` includes the build step already. Since Nuxt 2.13.0, `nuxt build && nuxt export` is a thing though because the "generate" part can now be split into a couple of commands

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks for adding that.